# java.lang.AssertionError: Cannot construct instance of java.lang.Enum

Tags: java, jackson, resteasy

I am developing a client/server application, that in the backend has some REST methods developed with RESTeasy.

Particularly, there is a **POST** method that, as input, takes a JSON string, and then returns another JSON to the calling client.

The conversion from JSON to a Java class is performed by Jackson in a transparent way, but I have this problem:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Can not construct instance of java.lang.Enum, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information

The JUnit Test that fails with this error is:

```
/**
 * Test for creation of json of {@link FindRequestBody}.
 */
@Test
public void testJackson2(){
    try {
        FindRequestBody findRequestBody = new FindRequestBody();        

        ObjectMapper jacksonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        File file = new File("c:\\testFindRequestBody.json");
        jacksonMapper.writeValue(file, findRequestBody);

        Path path = Paths.get("c:\\testFindRequestBody.json");
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

        FindRequestBody returned = jacksonMapper.readValue(data, FindRequestBody.class);

        Assert.assertNotNull(returned);

    } 
    catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
    } 
    catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The REST method is:

```
 /**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@POST
@Path("/filter")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Override
public List<Object> find(FindRequestBody findRequestBody){
    return service.find(findRequestBody);
}
```

The `JSON` taken as input from the method is, for example:

```
{     
   "orderReadContext":{  
      "valid":"VALID_ONLY"
   },
   "queryControl":{  
      "firstResult":0,
      "maxResults":-1,
      "sortOrder":[      
      ]
   }
}
```

The field valid is a field that maps an `Enum`. The FieldRequestBody class contains the OrderReadContext class that is:

```
public class OrderReadContext implements Serializable
{
    protected ValidOrAll valid = ValidOrAll.VALID_ONLY;

    public ValidOrAll getValid()
    {
        return this.valid;
    }

   public void setValid(ValidOrAll arg)
   {
        if (arg == null)
        {
            this.valid = ValidOrAll.VALID_ONLY;
        }
        else
        {
            this.valid = arg;
         }
    }
}
```

Probably caused by the fact that, in the Java class corresponding to the JSON, there are some fields that are `Enum`.

I cannot use annotations, so I want to know if it is possible to use some Providers, or Interceptors, etc.

Comment: Could you post some code? Rough guess: You're not using Java 5 or newer, on your server. To check the Java version on your server: `java -version`

Comment: Here's a quick tip - instead of catching all the exceptions in your test case, make the test method throw `Exception` and let all errors propagate up - you will get much better diagnostics when the test fails

Comment: My java version is: "1.8.0_40".

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea catching all exceptions in a single Exception block, but apart from this, the exception is clear, and depends on whether Jackson can not convert abstract fields when converting JSON -> Java Class.

Comment: what's in `FindRequestBody`?

Comment: show the java model for your json, please

Comment: Please post the `FindRequestBody` class and the class containing `Enum` object causing the problem.

Comment: Edited, added JSON and class with Enum field.

Comment: @user140888 I think you really need to include classes that @shruti1810 suggests, not just bits and pieces. Included classes seem ok, but the exception suggests something strange is indeed going on. `Enum`s should be handled with special deserializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem creating a Provider of this type:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonJsonProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonJsonProvider() throws Exception {
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        System.out.println("JacksonJsonProvider():: Enter Into Constructor");        
        /*
         * First, you can globally declare that certain types always require additional type information:           
         * objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(); // default to using DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE
         * what this means is that for all types specified (for no-args, "Object.class" and all non-final classes), certain amount of default type information (Java class name, more specifically), is included, using default inclusion mechanism (additional wrapper array in JSON). This global default can be overridden by per-class annotations (more on this in next section).
         * 
         * The only thing you can configure, then, is just which types (classes) are affected. Choices are:
         * JAVA_LANG_OBJECT: only affects properties of type Object.class
         * OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE: affects Object.class and all non-concrete types (abstract classes, interfaces)
         * NON_CONCRETE_AND+_ARRAYS: same as above, and all array types of the same (direct elements are non-concrete types or Object.class)
         * NON_FINAL: affects all types that are not declared 'final', and array types of non-final element types. 
         * This is often simplest initial way to enable enough type information to get things going. 
         */
         getObjectMapperForSerialization();

         System.out.println("JacksonJsonProvider():: Enabled Default Typing And Exit Constructor");
    }

    protected void getObjectMapperForSerialization() {
        System.out.println("JacksonJsonProvider():: Enter Into getObjectMapperForSerialization()");
        StdTypeResolverBuilder typeResolverBuilder = new ObjectMapper.DefaultTypeResolverBuilder(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE);
        typeResolverBuilder = typeResolverBuilder.inclusion(JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
        typeResolverBuilder.init(JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, new ClassNameIdResolver(SimpleType.construct(Base.class), TypeFactory.defaultInstance()));
        this.objectMapper.setDefaultTyping(typeResolverBuilder);
    }

    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

And registering it into web.xml, between resteasy-providers.